# question with epub files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, epub

I am developing a ebook reader for iPhone whic loads epub file.
I have unzipped the epub file.

What I am confused is, if I read HTML file from the extracted content of epub file, will it be fine?

or do I need to parse the container.xml also?

at present I am able to read only HTML file and I can see all the content with Webview.

is it enough if I read only HTML file?

Thanks...

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB and understand what it is you are looking at before you consider developing an app that you unleash on the public.

Comment: There it is all about epub and its files. I have already read them. My question is technically which if I can manage to read only HTML file, is that enough?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not enough.

1. How will you know what order the files should be displayed in?
2. How will you display the navigational structure?
3. How will you determine if the content you are reading is valid (users tend to be upset when apps crash on invalid data)?

Without using the facilities provided to you by the file format you are not going to write any application that processes EPUB files successfully.

You've asked a lot of questions about the EPUB format that seem to suggest that you don't really understand the file format. I think perhaps that you should read the specifications at the [IDPF website](http://www.idpf.org/) before you write  **any** code at all.

Answer (score 2):

from wikipedia "XML is used to create the document manifest, table of contents, and EPUB metadata." Sounds like you risk dropping the table of contents.